# How to use the configure command within Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to customize the compilation of curl-7.60.0 with Xcode.

I added it as an *External Build System* target. There is no problem if I build it as is, but I would like to change the *--prefix* option from the `./configure` command.

Need some help here please

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I just ran the `./configure` on the command prompt to generate the Makefile then go back to Xcode to build